# ActiveAdmin No method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I added a couple of foreign keys to my models and to my tables and it has since broken my use of Active Admin. I'm wondering if anyone knows a work around or a fix to this issue.

schmea.rb

```
create_table "students", primary_key: "student_id", id: :string, force: 
:cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "home_address"
    t.string "home_city"
    t.string "home_state"
    t.string "home_zip"
    t.string "school_year_address"
    t.string "school_year_city"
    t.string "school_year_zip"
    t.string "room_number"
    t.string "home_phone"
    t.string "cell_phone"
    t.boolean "new_student"
    t.boolean "returning_student"
    t.string "athletic_team"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "fk_rails_148c9e88f4"
end
add_foreign_key "emergency_contacts", "students", primary_key: "student_id"
add_foreign_key "students", "users"
add_foreign_key "vehicles", "students", primary_key: "student_id"
```

student.rb Students Model

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
    self.primary_key = :student_id
    belongs_to  :user
    has_one :emergency_contact
    has_one :vehicle
end
```

I'm getting the error, has anyone found a fix for this?

```
undefined method `emergency_contact_id_eq' for Ransack::Search<class: Student, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search
```

Comment: Try `emergency_contact_id_equals` instead of `emergency_contact_id_eq` https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages.html#index-filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the assocation wrong.

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
    self.primary_key = :student_id
    belongs_to  :user
    belongs_to :emergency_contact, class_name: 'User'
    has_one :vehicle
end
```

`belongs_to` places the foreign key on this table and is exactly what you want. When joining you want to have the id on this table instead of having to look for records where `student_id` matches this record.

You also need to make sure to add a foreign key column and the correct foreign key constraint:

```
class AddEmergencyContactIdToStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :students, :emergency_contact, foreign_key: false
    add_foreign_key :students, :users, column: :emergency_contact_id, 
  end
end
```

I would also strongly advise against using non standard primary keys. Prefixing the PK with `student_` gives you nothing but headaches and will confuse other developers.

Comment: For the first part where I am defining the association, I would be defining vehicle wrong as well, wouldn't I? I left out some tables because it was long, but basically the user will have one student, and the student will have one vehicle and one emergency contact, both which are separate tables. I was going to have every table have a user_id field that way I can control that the base users only see there own info and not everyone in the tables. Am I just mixing up my models?

Comment: Access control is done on the controller level - not by database design. You should avoid duplicating foreign keys on multiple levels. Plan your database from what is logical and effective to query/join.